# Where should Android App data be stored? How should I write to a file?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, file, file-io

Where should the CSV output text file from my Android App (writing in Eclipse) be stored. I currently use:

```
> File peopledetail_file = new File(this.getFilesDir(),
> "PeopleDetailsFile");
```

and

```
InputStream filestream = openFileInput("PeopleDetailsFile");
```

to access my file. This clearly does not work, as I get an error, saying it can't be found at this location

```
/data/data/com.example.partyorganiser/files/PeopleDetailsFile
```

Comment: I'm looking for a system of reading and writing text, in a simple way. It seems that the writer works, but writes in a different location to where the reader reads from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Creating a file you must call `peopledetail_file.createNewFile()` then write your file

```
File peopledetail_file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "PeopleDetailsFile");
peopledetail_file.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(peopledetail_file);
// do writing ...
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
pw.print("Hello");
pw.flush
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Comment: OK, thanks!! What should I use to read this back??? Thanks!! presumably fos.write(string) is used for writing?? :)

Comment: You can use a scanner to read it; fos.write(object) is for writing bytes in a file , for example writing bytes of an object in a file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use `openFileInput()`, use `openFileOutput()`.

If you are going to use `getFilesDir()` for output, use `getFilesDir()` for input.

Comment: Nope, but I think I know the problem. It doesn't create the file, when writing. How can I specify that?? thanks for the help!! :)

Comment: @SwedishArchitect: You create the file by writing to it. This is standard Java I/O.

Comment: yeah I thought that as well, but the error message says - "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.partyorganiser/files/PeopleDetailsFile: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)" when writing to it...